# Cron view on VPS

Tags: cron

How can I view all cron jobs scheduled on my Linux Ubuntu VPS? When I use crontab -l I do get a list of cronjobs but I cannot see the ones that are scheduled by WordPress, how can I also see the ones that each WP installation is scheduling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress cron jobs are often not system cron jobs, they are just scheduled within the wordpress configuration and triggered when a visitor arrives at the site near the time when the cron job is set to be exectuted.  In order to work out when they occur, you would need to check the table within wordpress that they are stored in.

If you want to check system cronjobs, then as root, you can look in the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory, which contains a crontab file for each user that has cron jobs configured, named after their user account.

Comment: Thanks the file I found has the same contents as when using crontab -l command. I was afraid that my htaccess was being rewritten via a cronjob (site was hacked), but it seems it is not so as there are no such crons here, and neither in the WordPress install, which I've checked using a plugin to view WP crons.

Comment: If the site was compromised, then any of the wordpress files could potentially be overwriting the .htaccess files.  It is very likely that several of the files have backdoors.  Your best approach is to take a backup of the datebase, delete all the files, re-install and restore.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I've done, although there is still a chance that some of the content related files were infected. I cannot just delete those of course.